# Result of two methods in one array

Tags: java, arrays

I have two methods, both of them are returning the String array . Now, I have another method so , I want to use the arrays which are returned by these two methods .So, Single String  array will be there and which will contain the arrays returned by these two methods .So, How can i do that ?
My code is like

```
private String[] getAllRZFiles() {
        FilenameFilter filenamefilter = new RegexFileFilter("^" + PREFIX_RZ_FILES + ".*\\" + SUFFIX_RZ_FILES + "$");
       // FilenameFilter filenameFilterJob = new RegexFileFilter("^(" + PREFIX_RZ_FILES + ".*\\" + SUFFIX_RZ_FILES + "|" + PREFIX_RZJD_FILES + ".*\\" +SUFFIX_RZ_FILES + ")$");
        return new File(AppConstants.GAZETTEER_PATH).list(filenamefilter);
    }



  private String[] getAllCommonFiles(){
        FilenameFilter filenamefilter = new RegexFileFilter("^" + PREFIX_CO_FILES + ".*\\" + SUFFIX_RZ_FILES + "$");
        return new File(AppConstants.GAZETTEER_PATH).list(filenamefilter);
    }
```

This are my two methods .

and I want to use it in

```
public String getcontent() throws Exception{

String [] result ;

}
```

Here In result array ,I want the output of both the methods .

Comment: `System.arrayCopy` is your friend

Answer (score 4):

You can use `System.arraycopy`

```
public static <T> T[] concat(T[] first, T[] second) {
  T[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, first.length + second.length);
  System.arraycopy(second, 0, result, first.length, second.length);
  return result;
}
```

Or in Java 8, you can achieve this using `stream`

```
String[] both = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b))
                      .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try concating the string arrays into one.

You can use the Apache Commons Lang library

```
String[] both = (String[])ArrayUtils.addAll(firstArr, secondArr);
```

**OR**

If adding 3rd party library is considered as an overkill for you then I would use Java's ArrayList,

`List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();`

I will iterate through both string arrays and add the resultant string to the ArrayList.

```
resultList.add("array-A-and-B-Result");
```

Lastly convert the arrayList back to a string array or you can simply just change the parameter of your other fn to take in ArrayList as it is easier to manipulate the element.

```
String[] combinedResult = new String[resultList.size()];
combinedResult = resultList.toArray(combinedResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the Apache Commons Lang Library you can use something like

```
String[] result = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(array1, array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any library, you can do it the manual way :

```
String[] both = new String[firstArray.length + secondArray.length];
for (int i=0; i<firstArray.length; i++) { both[i]=firstArray[i]; }
for (int j=0; j<secondArray.length; j++) { both[firstArray.length+j]=secondArray[j]; }
```

Or with arrayCopy :

```
both = new String[firstArray.length + secondArray.length];
System.arraycopy(firstArray, 0, both, 0, firstArray.length);
System.arraycopy(secondArray, 0, both, firstArray.length, secondArray.length);
```

Or by using lists :

```
List<String> bothAsList = Arrays.asList(firstArray);
bothAsList.addAll(Arrays.asList(secondArray));
both = bothAsList.toArray(new String[0]);
```